# Rxjs - Calculate time spent inside/outside a div

Tags: rxjs

I am learning Rxjs and wanted to try out a few examples on my own
but I can't seem to get my head around to think reactively.

I am trying to calculate the time a user's mouse pointer spends inside and outside a div.

see fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ishansoni22/44af3n3k/

```
<div class = "space">
<div>

let $space = $(".space")

let in$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, "mouseenter")
                       .map((event) => "in")
let out$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, "mouseleave")                                    
                       .map((event) => "out")

let inOut$ = Rx.Observable.merge(in$, out$)

let time$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
                     .buffer(inOut$)
                     .map((list) => list.length)

time$.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
```

I am able to calculate the time but how do I relate it to the respective in/ out streams? I want the output to look something like :

- inside, in - 20, out - 30
- outside, in - 20, out - 35
- inside, in - 100, out - 35

Also, can someone point me to some examples I could do so that I can start thinking in the reactive paradigm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some examples in the official documentation (http://reactivex.io/rxjs) but they are a little bit scarce indeed.

I think I would some your sample something like this:

```
let $space = $(".space")
let in$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, "mouseenter")
let out$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, "mouseleave")

let durations$ = in$
  .map(_ => Date.now())
  .switchMap(inTime => out$
    .take(1)
    .map(_ => Date.now())
    .map(outTime => outTime - inTime)
  )

durations$
  .scan((sum, next) => sum + next, 0)
  .subscribe(total => console.log(total))
```

This would start listening to in$, then upon a `mouseenter`-event it starts to listen to `mouseleaves`, takes 1 of those events and calculate the duration.

I have written multiple maps below each other for clarity, but of course you can compose that into a single function.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I found most challenging when starting out with Rx was using streams of streams, and becoming comfortable with `flatMap` and `switchMap`. The problem you describe is most easily solved using exactly this approach. With your streams defined as follows (I prefer `const` over `let` to make it clear no mutation is occuring):

```
const in$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, 'mouseenter');
const out$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, 'mouseleave');
```

you can describe entering and then leaving as follows:

```
const inThenOut$ = in$.switchMap(() => out$);
```

To understand exactly what this is doing I urge you to learn about `flatMap`, become comfortable with streams of streams, and then learn how `switchMap` works by only maintaining a subscription to the most recent inner stream. For this I found the official rxjs documentation the best source. The included marble diagrams often tell complex stories with just a few dots and lines.

From here it's a relatively small step to get the time spent inside. First, we map our original streams into timestamp values:

```
const timestamp = () => + new Date();
const in$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, 'mouseenter').map(() => timestamp());
const out$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($space, 'mouseleave').map(() => timestamp());
```

(note: there is a `timestamp` method in rxjs you could use instead of doing this manually, but I feel this better illustrates how you can map your stream elements into anything you please).

From there, we can adjust our `switchMap` usage to access both the in and out values, and return the difference between them:

```
const inThenOut$ = in$.switchMap(() => out$, (x, y) => y - x);
```

Here's the whole thing working:

https://jsbin.com/qoruyoluho/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RXJS - Timestamp operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timestamp.html) to attach timestamp to each item emitted by an Observable indicating when it was emitted.

```
const { fromEvent } = Rx;
const { map, switchMap, timestamp, take, tap } = RxOperators;

const in$ = fromEvent($space, 'mouseenter').pipe(
  timestamp(),
  tap(x => console.log(`In: ${x.timestamp}`))
)

const out$ = fromEvent($space, 'mouseleave').pipe(
  timestamp(),
  tap(x => console.log(`Out: ${x.timestamp}`))
)

const duration$ = in$.pipe(
  switchMap(start => out$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(finish => finish.timestamp - start.timestamp),
      tap(value => console.log(`Duration ms: ${value}`))
    )
  )
)

/* output example
In: 1552295324302
Out: 1552295325158
Duration ms: 856
*/
```

Try it here: https://rxviz.com/v/rOW5g9x8